# Is it possible to create a ggplot with interactions with tidy evaluation

Tags: r, ggplot2, rlang, tidyeval

I am trying to create a plot function that can plot different colors for a column with factors if .f2=NULL, and an interaction of the .f1 and .f2 columns if the .f2 parameter is not NULL.
The if statement already doesn't work when .f2 is not NULL. After that I try to create the interaction call but that doesn't work.

I'm aware I can also create an if statement that creates two seperate aes functions but I was wondering if I could do it like below.

```
input = tibble(x=1:100,y=rnorm(100),f1=factor(rep(c("c",'d'),each=50)),f2=factor(rep(c("a",'b'),50)))

plot_interaction = function(.df, .x, .y, .f1, .f2=NULL) {

  if (!is.null(.f2)) {
     .en1 = .f1 |> enexpr() |> as.character()
     .en2 = .f2 |> enexpr() |> as.character()
     .expr=paste0('interaction(',.en1,',',.en2,')')
     .expr = expr(.expr)
  } else
    .expr = ensym(.f1)
  
  ggplot(.df, aes(x = {{ .x }}, y = {{ .y }}, colour = {{ .expr}})) + 
    geom_point(size = 4, alpha = 0.5)
}

plot_interaction(input, x, y, f1)

plot_interaction(input,x, y, f1, f2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `missing` rather than `is.null` to avoid your specific error.

However, your code won't generate interactions in the event of `.f2` being present, because then your conditional will output an *expression* containing the symbol `.expr` rather than a *quosure* containing the parsed code you wish to inject. One option is to use `rlang::parse_quo` rather than `expr`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

input <- tibble(x = 1:100, y = rnorm(100), 
                f1 = factor(rep(c("c", 'd'), each = 50)),
                f2 = factor(rep(c("a", 'b'), 50)))

plot_interaction <- function(.df, .x, .y, .f1, .f2) {
  
  if(missing(.f2)) {
    .expr <- ensym(.f1) 
  } else {
    .en1 <- .f1 |> enexpr() |> as.character()
    .en2 <- .f2 |> enexpr() |> as.character()
    .expr <- paste0('interaction(', .en1, ',', .en2, ')')
    .expr <- rlang::parse_quo(.expr, env = parent.frame())
  }
  
  ggplot(.df, aes(x = {{ .x }}, y = {{ .y }}, colour = {{ .expr}})) + 
    geom_point(size = 4, alpha = 0.5)
}
```

This now allows:

```r
plot_interaction(input, x, y, f1)
```

[image]

And

```r
plot_interaction(input,x, y, f1, f2)
```

[image]